# Modbus RTU using SoftwareSerial

Tags: arduino, communication, rs232

Im trying to control a temperature controller using Arduino MEGA over SoftwareSerial.

Im using [Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino](https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino) library and I tried to test using example code below.
It gives only `0` for each item of the received data array `au16data[]`.

Im using [RS-485 serial transceiver module](https://hobbycomponents.com/wired-wireless/663-max485-rs485-transceiver-module) for interface to temperature controller and SoftwareSerial pins. But, There is no any pin definition for DE and RE pins. How can I connect A and B terminal of the controller to Arduino?

```
#include <ModbusRtu.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// data array for modbus network sharing
uint16_t au16data[16];
uint8_t u8state;

/**
 *  Modbus object declaration
 *  u8id : node id = 0 for master, = 1..247 for slave
 *  u8serno : serial port (use 0 for Serial)
 *  u8txenpin : 0 for RS-232 and USB-FTDI 
 *               or any pin number > 1 for RS-485
 */
Modbus master(0); // this is master and RS-232 or USB-FTDI via software serial

/**
 * This is an structe which contains a query to an slave device
 */
modbus_t telegram;

unsigned long u32wait;

SoftwareSerial mySerial(12, 13);//Create a SoftwareSerial object so that we can use software serial. Search "software serial" on Arduino.cc to find out more details.

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);//use the hardware serial if you want to connect to your computer via usb cable, etc.
  master.begin( &mySerial, 9600 ); // begin the ModBus object. The first parameter is the address of your SoftwareSerial address. Do not forget the "&". 9600 means baud-rate at 9600
  master.setTimeOut( 2000 ); // if there is no answer in 2000 ms, roll over
  u32wait = millis() + 1000;
  u8state = 0; 
}

void loop() {
  switch( u8state ) {
  case 0: 
    if (millis() > u32wait) u8state++; // wait state
    break;
  case 1: 
    telegram.u8id = 0x01; // slave address
    telegram.u8fct = 0x04; // function code (this one is registers read)
    telegram.u16RegAdd = 0x03E8; // start address in slave
    telegram.u16CoilsNo = 0x01; // number of elements (coils or registers) to read
    telegram.au16reg = au16data; // pointer to a memory array in the Arduino

    master.query( telegram ); // send query (only once)
    u8state++;
    break;
  case 2:
    master.poll(); // check incoming messages
    if (master.getState() == COM_IDLE) {
      u8state = 0;
      u32wait = millis() + 2000; 
        Serial.println(au16data[0]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[1]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[2]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[3]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[4]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[5]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[6]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[7]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[8]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[9]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[10]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[11]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[12]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[13]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[14]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[15]);//Or do something else!
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you use SoftwareSerial on a MCU with 4 hardware Serials?

Comment: Actually Im testing my project. I have already made a PCB. I will change to HardwareSerial in next version.

Comment: I am testing your above code with a Modbus 32-Input board, using an Arduino Nano and generic TTL to RS485 module.  My hardware communicates fine using Radzio! Modbus tester.  My thought to you is, this example https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino/blob/master/examples/simple_master/simple_master.ino  uses decimal numbers for the 5 Case 1 telegram values, not Hex.  Does that matter?  Reading my 32-input board with this returns all Zeros not Ones also, not Ones when there is an input.  Did you revise this to read the correct values?

Answer (score 1):

These appear to be Driver Output and Receiver Output enable pins.

Your website link shows that you should do the following to these pins

> RE..........Receiver Output Enable (Low to enable)
>
> DE..........Driver Output Enable (high to enable)

Enables are not part of RS-485 and so won't be handled by the library, you'll have to control these pins yourself by using a `DigitalWrite()` before you transmit/receive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
According to web site DE+RE should HIGH when transmitting and DE+RE should LOW when reeving. This should be done in library.

Comment: Good point, it looks like you should just hook these inputs up to some GPIOs and toggle them yourself.

Comment: Yes. I have added it to my code. After `case 1:` line, put DE+RE to HIGH and after `case 2:`, DE+RE put LOW. 
Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Use RE+DE pin number when initializing the Modbus object like below. There is optional parameter for DE+RE pin.

```
#define SSerialTxControl 8
master.begin( &mySerial, 9600, SSerialTxControl );
```

This is the library function,

```
  /**
   * @brief
   * Initialize class object.
   *
   * Sets up the software serial port using specified baud rate and SoftwareSerial object.
   * Call once class has been instantiated, typically within setup().
   *
   * @param *sPort     pointer to SoftwareSerial class object
   * @param u32speed   baud rate, in standard increments (300..115200)
   * **@param u8txenpin  pin for txen RS-485 (=0 means USB/RS232C mode)**
   * @ingroup setup
   */
  void Modbus::begin(SoftwareSerial *sPort, long u32speed, uint8_t u8txenpin)
  {

    this->u8txenpin=u8txenpin;
      softPort=sPort;

      softPort->begin(u32speed);

      if (u8txenpin > 1)   // pin 0 & pin 1 are reserved for RX/TX
      {
          // return RS485 transceiver to transmit mode
          pinMode(u8txenpin, OUTPUT);
          digitalWrite(u8txenpin, LOW);
      }

      while(softPort->read() >= 0);
      u8lastRec = u8BufferSize = 0;
      u16InCnt = u16OutCnt = u16errCnt = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code and hardware are correct base on reading [0]. Please take note in this line:
telegram.u16CoilsNo = 0x01; // number of elements (coils or registers) to read

You should change it to more than 1 (number of register you want to read).